# contact notes are not transferred when exporting/importing via the built-in vCard representation methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, abaddressbook, vcf-vcard

Using the ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople method for export, and the ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation for import, I have successfully transfered contact data between devices. However, the data in the contact's "notes" field isn't transfered.
Here's my export function:

```
+(NSData*)exportContactsToVcard:(NSArray*)contacts
{
    NSMutableArray *people  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:contacts.count];
    ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
    for (Contact *contact in contacts) 
    {
        ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab,contact.contactId);
        [people addObject:(__bridge id)person];
    }
    NSData *vCard = (__bridge NSData*)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople((__bridge CFArrayRef) people);
    return vCard;
}
```

and part of my import function:

```
+(NSArray*)importContactsFromVcardData:(NSData*)vcardData
{
    NSMutableArray *addedContactIds = [NSMutableArray array];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
    NSArray *createdPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource,(__bridge CFDataRef)vcardData);
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    for (id person in createdPeople)
    {
        error = NULL;
        ABRecordRef personRecord = (__bridge ABRecordRef)person;
        NSString *notes = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(personRecord, kABPersonNoteProperty);
```

In the last line, notes is always nil, even if the contact had notes before it was exported. All the other standard contact fields seem to be in place.
For example, if I replace the last line with:

```
NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(personRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

the firstName string will hold the contact's first name.

Any idea how I can work around this, and get the contact notes?

Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me how create vcf file for all contact in iphone .

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes, you can export a vCard from Address Book.  Then drag it to TextEdit to look at the various fields.

At the bottom you'll find something like this:

NOTE:This is a note!

Also, see this link for info on the vCard format:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

Answer (score 0):

ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople will only transfer the important contact details of a vCard...thats my identifying in much tests with the vCard and the iOS import-export function. It has many mistakes, e.g. if you try to import it with social networks like facebook, it won't do it with (just look in my other thread [THREADLINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589216/cfarraygetvalueatindex-wont-get-the-social-profiles) )

But if you try to add some vCard Information over ABNewPersonViewController, it will work perfectly.